# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException. After update android studio 1.5 to 2.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I just update Android Studio 1.5 to 2.1.
My project don't work.

**Error is:**

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: it.PACKAGE, PID: 20378
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{PACKAGE._activities.LoginActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53: Error
>   inflating class it.PACKAGE.componentlibrary._View.VQEditorText
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2534)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2614)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5643)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53: Error inflating class PACKAGE_activities._View.VQEditorText
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
>          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
>          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>          at it.PACKAGE._activities.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:61)
>          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6100)
>          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2614) 
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
>          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5643) 
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960) 
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "PACKAGE_activities.componentlibrary._View.VQEditorText" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/PACKAGE_activities/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64,
>   /system/lib64]]
>          at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:571)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
>          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
>          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>          at it.PACKAGE._activities.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:61) 
>          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6100) 
>          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112) 
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481) 
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2614) 
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
>          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5643) 
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960) 
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
>       Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "PACKAGE_activities.componentlibrary._View.VQEditorText" on path:
>   DexPathList[[dex file
>   "/data/data/it.PACKAGE/files/instant-run/dex/slice-xz-1.5_4f64227c18dd7f56414814a88b2619c2b420c2e2-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/it.PACKAGE/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-23.4.0_97e8c3f8ffa9a0d8a11737951980b192082ddaf7-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/PACKAGE_activities/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/it.PACKAGE/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/it.PACKAGE/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/it.PACKAGE/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/it.PACKAGE/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/it.PACKAGE/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/it.PACKAGE/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/it.PACKAGE/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex",
>   dex file "/data/data/it.PACKAGE/files/instant-ru

The class:
`PACKAGE_activities.componentlibrary._View.VQEditorText` is into my library module.

**gradle module app :**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "it.PACKAGE"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(path: ':componentlibrary')
    compile project(':tableview')

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.code-troopers.betterpickers:library:2.5.3'
    compile 'com.splitwise:tokenautocomplete:2.0.7@aar'

}
```

**gradle componentlibrary:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
}
```

I tried :

- Clean Project
- Rebuild Project
- File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart

but nothing.
Anyone know about it? Any Solution?

Comment: check it.PACKAGE.componentlibrary._View.VQEditorText

Comment: Why would someone upvote this question?

Comment: @MarkShen VQEditorText is a simple class. It extends AppCompatEditText. But it is inner module library android and in my module app, I add in gradle my module library dependences.

Comment: post you gradle file..

Comment: @WaqarYounis I just added gradle..

Comment: I removed VQEditText and now there is another error class not found inner my library. "componentlibrary" is the problem. But why?